# Append to text area with PrintWriter intead of replacing it

Tags: java, servlets

I want to append the message entered in the form to the text area instead of replacing it using the doPost method of HttpServlet. I have only managed to completely replace the html...

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        // dont redirect to a new page, but write the response directly to the response object
        out.println("<form action=\"hello-servlet\" method=\"post\" target=\"chat\">");
        out.println("Message: <input type=\"text\" name=\"message\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>");
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("<textarea name=\"chatoutput\" id=\"chat\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\"readonly>");
        out.println("Hello");

        out.println("</textarea>");

        out.println("</body></html>");


    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String message = req.getParameter("message");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the chat somewhere. You could use a database or a file. An alternative place is to use a Servlet member variable. Of course chat will be lost when the server is shutdown. Here is demonstration code.

```
package rick;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    String chat = "Hello <br>";
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        String message = req.getParameter("message");
        if(message != null && !"".equals(message.trim())) {
            chat += message + "<br>" ;
        }
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<form action=\"hello-servlet\" method=\"post\" >");
        out.println("Message: <input type=\"text\" name=\"message\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println(chat);
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp); 
    }
}
```